# jQuery expression return 'undefined' in iPad Safari

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari, svg

I am working on SVG paper, and I need to get the value of first **tspan** element of **text** elements, which is placed before **rect** elements with jQuery.

This code:

```
var rects = jQuery("#holder").find("rect");
jQuery.each(rects, function(){
    var temp = jQuery(this).prev().find('tspan:first')[0];
    console.log(jQuery(temp).text());
})
```

works perfectly in Chrome, FF and IE9. But it returns 'undefined' only in Safari on iPad. I have no idea, what is wrong with this code and why Safari interpretation differs from all other browsers. I would be glad to recieve any advice.

Comment: Does `console.log(jQuery(temp))` or `console.log(temp)` show up?

Comment: Is the first line returning the rects correctly?

Comment: I think it is correct if it works in three browsers

Comment: Well the rest works correctly as well in three browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I avoid mixing jQuery with SVG because of edge cases like this. Try a partial selection of the elements with vanilla js:

```
var rects = $("#holder").find("rect");
$.each(rects, function(){
    temp = this.previousElementSibling.querySelector("tspan")
    console.log($(temp).text());
})​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h8Uc7/

Or better yet, just use vanilla js, it's just as simple and way faster:

```
var rects = document.querySelectorAll("#holder rect");
for (i=0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    temp = rects[i].previousElementSibling.querySelector("tspan")
    console.log(temp.textContent);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aE5mq/